# how to add together the items in a list after a certain condition is true?

Tags: python, function, if-statement

I am trying to write a value return function in which the parameter is a list of records that show store sales and number of employees and such.

The function iterates through the record list and calculates the total number

of employees from stores with sales volume more than $50,000.

the "records" parameter is an txt file that contains the information
in the following format:
Hm001,6,Frankton,42305.67
id, num of employees, suburb, sales count

I have written a if statement for the stores that earn more than 50000.
**I need help  with showing the total number of employees from stores that have sales return of more than 50000.**

the solution must be general and work for any list with the same format.
Please explain your answer as I am new to python.

```
def count_employees(records):
   num_of_emp = ""
   for count in records: 
      if count[3] > 50000: 
         num_of_emp = 
   return count
```

**EDIT** this is the sample records:

```
Hm001,6,Frankton,42305.67
Hm002,10,Glenview,21922.22
Hm003,7,Silverdale,63277.9
Hm004,13,Glenview,83290.09
Hm005,21,Queenwood,81301.82
Hm006,14,Hillcrest,62333.3
Hm007,7,Frankton,28998.8
Hm008,19,Chartwell,51083.5
Hm009,6,Glenview,62155.72
Hm0010,8,Enderley,33075.1
Hm0011,10,Fairfield,61824.7
Hm0012,15,Rototuna,21804.8
Hm0013,11,Fairfield,62804.7
```

Comment: Is that really what your file data looks like? It appears to be structured with up to three records per line which is a bit cumbersome. Please show how you're constructing your records list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work. Don't tested it tho:

```
file = "text.txt"

def count_employees(filename):
    num_of_emp = 0
    with open(filename) as f:
        all_data = f.readlines()
        lines = all_data[0].split(" ")
        for line in lines:
            record = line.split(",")
            if float(record[3]) > 50000:
                num_of_emp += int(record[1])
    return num_of_emp

print(count_employees(file))
```

Comment: This cannot possibly work for the data shown in the question. Why it's become the accepted answer is therefore very mysterious

Comment: I edited my awnser, because the question was edited. Can you tell what's wrong with it?

Comment: There are up to 3 records per line in the data. This simply doesn't handle that. See my answer to learn how it should be done

Comment: You are right. Corrected it. text-file seems to be one long line.

Comment: The data, as shown in the question, is multiple records on multiple lines

Comment: I copied the data into a file and there are no line breaks.

Comment: Your awnser is the right one tho...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245475/discussion-between-albert-winestein-and-laserface000).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

The input data is comprised of records such as:

```
Hm001,6,Frankton,42305.67
```

There is one record per line in the input file. (This is an edit after OP reformatted the inout data in the original question).

```
FILENAME = 'foo.txt'
VOLUME = 50_000

def emp_count(filename):
    count = 0
    with open(filename) as data:
        for line in data:
            _, emps, _, sales = line.split(',')
            if float(sales) > VOLUME:
                count += int(emps)
    return count


print(emp_count(FILENAME))
```

**Output: (based on the sample data shown in the question)**

```
101
```

**Edit:**

Code simplified after change to OP's question indicates that there's only one record per line

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you having an issue with? Can you be more specific in what you don't understand? Your problem can be easily researched

You have initialised num_of_emp incorrectly:

`num_of_emp = "" # this should not be an empty string`

You are also returning the incorrect variable as 'count' only exists within the for loop.

Comment: right. I am having an issue with adding the number of employees from the stores that earn more than 50000. as shown in my code, i have a if statement for this but now i dont know if how to do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so for adding a new element to the list, you can make use of `.append()`
it adds a new element to the list.

so the syntax goes like:

```
list_name.append(element)
```

and from the code you have given, I think `num_of_emp` should be an empty list.

```
num_of_emp = []
```

not an empty string----> `""`

So, If you could be more specific, that would be helpful.

Comment: Based on **_So, If you could be more specific, that would be helpful._** This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/31990893)

Answer (score 0):

```
def count_smth(records):
    result = 0
    for count in records:
        if condition:
            result += 1
    return result
```

If you want to return **number**, specify `result` value as 0.
Your function returns `count`, not the result.
You can pass in if any condition, even write another function that returns boolean value.
`a += value` syntax makes the same thing as a = a + value

Answer (score -1):

Two options:

1 - In Python, in this case you can return a list containing only the best employees like the code below. Then you could simply get the count of these best employees accessing the length method of the list.

```
def count_employees(records):
   num_of_emp = []
   for employee in records: 
      if float(employee[3]) > 50000: 
         num_of_emp.append(employee) 
   return num_of_emp
```

However, you will need to create another list in the class where you call this function in order to get correctly the returned list. For instance in main.py

```
best_employees = []
records = [ <WHATEVER DATA YOU HAVE>]

best_employees = count_employees(records) #To get the list with the best employees
count_of_best_employees = best_employees.len() #To get the count of the best employees
```

2 - If you only want to get the counter then you would do this:

```
def count_employees(records):
   counter_best_employees = 0
   for employee in records: 
      if float(employee[3]) > 50000: 
         counter_best_employees = counter_best_employees + 1
   
return counter_best_employees
```

Python is one of the highest level lenguages I know and probably there is some kind of function that returns directly what you want without iterating the list yourself, but this will do for now.

Comment: *employee[3]* is a string

Comment: @AlbertWinestein
he added that point after my response....